# Trying to install MySQL, lots of brew doctor errors

Tags: osx-lion, mysql, homebrew

In OS X Lion I couldn't install `mysql`. I get this when typing `brew install mysql`

```
Error: You must `brew link cmake' before mysql can be installed
```

so then I type `brew link cmake`

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.8... 
Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.8/share/doc/cmake
/usr/local/share/doc is not writable. You should change its permissions.
```

When I typed `brew doctor` I get this:

> **Error:** "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories. `./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to
>   determine if software packages are installed, and what additional
>   flags to use when compiling and linking.
>
> Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed
>   via Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew
>   provided script of the same name. We found the following "config"
>   scripts:
>
> ```
> /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/curl-config
> /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncurses5-config
> /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncursesw5-config
> /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config
> /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xml2-config
> /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xslt-config
> ```
>
> **Error:** gettext was detected in your PREFIX. The gettext provided by Homebrew is "keg-only", meaning it does not get linked into your
>   PREFIX by default.
>
> If you `brew link gettext` then a large number of brews that don't
>   otherwise have a `depends_on 'gettext'` will pick up gettext anyway
>   during the `./configure` step.
>
> If you have a non-Homebrew provided gettext, other problems will
>   happen especially if it wasn't compiled with the proper architectures.
>
> **Error:** Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib. If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when building
>   Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
>
> Unexpected dylibs:
>       /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libboost_serialization-mt.dylib
>   /usr/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib
>   /usr/local/lib/libencfs.6.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
>   /usr/local/lib/libmacfuse_i32.2.dylib
>   /usr/local/lib/libmacfuse_i64.2.dylib
>   /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i32.2.dylib
>   /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i64.2.dylib
>   /usr/local/lib/librlog.5.0.0.dylib
>
> **Error:** Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib. If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
>   building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
>
> Unexpected .la files:
>       /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i32.la    /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i64.la
>
> **Error:** Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig. If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
>   building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
>
> Unexpected .pc files:
>       /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/osxfuse.pc
>
> **Error:** You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on those kegs to
>   fail to run properly once built.
>
> ```
> cmake
> ```
>
> **Error:** Your pkg-config is not checking "/usr/X11/lib/pkgconfig" for packages. Earlier versions of the pkg-config formula did not add
>   this path to the search path, which means that other formula may not
>   be able to find certain dependencies.
>
> To resolve this issue, re-brew pkg-config with:   brew rm pkg-config
>   && brew install pkg-config
>
> **Error:** You have a non-Homebrew 'pkg-config' in your PATH:   /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config
>
> `./configure` may have problems finding brew-installed packages using
>   this other pkg-config.
>
> **Error:** Your Xcode is configured with an invalid path. You should change it to the correct path. Please note that there is no correct
>   path at this time if you have *only* installed the Command Line Tools
>   for Xcode. If your Xcode is pre-4.3 or you installed the whole of
>   Xcode 4.3 then one of these is (probably) what you want:
>
> ```
> sudo xcode-select -switch /Developer
> sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
> ```
>
> DO NOT SET / OR EVERYTHING BREAKS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this is just because you don't fully own `/usr/local`. It's actually what the error message says. Try:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
```

See if that fixes the errors.

Comment: okay thanks, that fixed the first part (the long list one)

Comment: Can you install MySQL though? The `doctor` messages may not be that important. Please update your question if possible and indent the output with `Ctrl-K`, not by blockquoting it. Thanks!

Comment: when I was first installing mysql I got an error that showed up about cmake so it didn't install. now it's telling me i must have cmake

I bold out the errors in the op so it's easier to read

Comment: Well, can or can you not `brew link cmake` and then `brew install mysql`? As I already said, you can forget what `brew doctor` says if you can install everything normally.

Comment: oh `brew link cmake` actually works now so `brew install mysql` worked as well thanks =D
should I ignore everything else then?

Comment: My `brew doctor` log is full of warnings, I learned to live with that. It's a good source for debugging though if something does not work.